# What is the difference between setting the DNS "A" record and changing nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I'm transferring web hosting for one domain from provider A to provider B. Now what I want is only the web server is to be transferred excluding the email hosting.

Which settings I'll do in order to get what result I wanted to have?

1. Setting the DNS "A" record or
2. Changing the nameservers

Comment: What do you mean by "Changing the nameservers" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [serverfault.com/questions/116359](http://serverfault.com/questions/116359) ?

Comment: This question shows a distinct lack of understanding of DNS fundamentals, as well as a lack to do your own research in an age where this information is easily available online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll answer the question in 2 stages:

**1. *What is setting the DNS “A” record***

the "A" record usually maps ip address to hostname

For example

your servers ip address is: 10.10.10.10
your domain name is: yoursite.com

so your A record will be

```
yoursite.com   IN      A       10.10.10.10
```

From the A record you can branch out prt and c names

For example a cname would be: blog.yoursite.com

**2. *Changing name servers***

This is literally changing your dns provider from one company to another.

So to answer your question you need to migrate all your records from your old DNS provider to your new one

Answer (score 2):

You just have to change the `A` record to match your webserver's new IP address.